# Is wheat gluten (wheat protein) an acceptible cooking substitute for soy protein powder or rice protein powder?

Tags: substitutions, vegetarian, vegan, vital-wheat-gluten

I'm trying a handful of vegan dishes, and have found a broth recipe which requires a small amount of soy or rice protein powder (1Tbsp).  This eventually makes 30 cups of broth, so overall is a very small component.

I have wheat gluten available, and am wondering if it would be an acceptible substitute; or if I would be better off leaving it out altogether, or with another substitute (presuming the protein is used to slightly thicken the broth, would corn starch be a 1:1 substitution)?

Full recipe [here](http://veganfeastkitchen.blogspot.com/2008/02/homemade-veggie-broth-powder-big-batch.html)

Answer (score 3):

Vital wheat gluten will not dissolve as those two isolates will. Vital what gluten would likelier clot. [Here](http://www.makeitlowcarb.com/mailbag_soyflourandprotein.htm) its a description of the difference between soy flour and soy protein isolate; although VWG is basically a protein isolate (it is the leftover from washing away the starch in wheat), like those powders, the other two are gluten free. However, like with any flour, you can use it as a slurry to avoid this problem